# Can you help with getting some statistics on Stack Overflow voting patterns?

Tags: support, voting, vote-to-close, data-explorer, data-analysis

About 2 weeks ago we've said good-bye to some *old* close reasons (*minimal understanding, describe specific problem, etc*). Since then, I think I might have noticed a drop in the amount of votes to close being cast. Before the *old* close reasons were removed I have seen fewer downvotes and more votes to close - specifically on poor questions. Now, it's the other way around - I see more downvotes on poor questions and 0 or a very low number of close votes cast.

Just quietly thinking, is it because the current close reasons make it harder to find the right reason or are my suspicions incorrect?

I am not clever enough myself to show some proof - picking odd questions would not prove anything. I am thinking more like a chart of how many close votes we have had in the last 2 weeks vs. the 2 before that, so if someone could do that, it would be great. I wouldn't yet want to reveal my judgement on the topic, but **would like to ask some friendly users to help show some statistics *if possible*.**

I know about the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) and I have looked through available queries but wasn't able to find what I am looking for. As I am not very good at creating queries I'd like someone with more experience to create a query /queries to grab the raw data - I can myself create a visual representation and a comparison between downvotes vs. votes to close cast from the last 2 weeks vs. 2 weeks before that (starting 4 weeks back, let's say 1st of January).

Comment: It may very well be "working as intended"--after all, look at the tooltip on the downvote button. I'm not taking one side or the other on whether it's good or not, but it would seem to fit with "do the right thing for the right reason". Given how aggressively SE went after stuff that was wrongly flagged for the right reason, I wouldn't be surprised if closures are being similarly targeted. And because downvotes don't require a reason, they're never "incorrect". But again, this is all just a theory.

Comment: Something about close votes is broken. I've brought it up with [tim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/209637) in [chat], but [queries aren't returning close votes properly after the close changes in June 2013](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/163740/208751/close-votes-cast-per-day). Once that gets fixed you can diddle the linked query to get your answer.